# How to specifiy the start directory for the CruiseControl service wrapper under windows

Tags: cruisecontrol

CruiseControl has a nice service wrapper for windows to start  CruiseControl automatically on booting up the computer. This could be very helpful if only the wrapper would not start CruiseControl in the installation directory.

Honestly: which self respecting build manager would mix build work and configuration files and application file of the build tool in one directory structure?

None of course. So is there a way to specify the directory in which wrapper.exe start the CruiseControl? Or any alternative trick to archive a similar result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `wrapper.working.dir` to archive this. Note that `wrapper.working.dir` will result in a change directory somewhere along the line so you should make all path names in your `wrapper.conf` absolute:

```
  6  wrapper.working.dir=C:/Work/CruiseControl
 16  wrapper.java.classpath.1=C:/opt/CruiseControl/2.8.4/lib/wrapper/*.jar
 17  wrapper.java.classpath.2=C:/opt/CruiseControl/2.8.4/lib/*.jar
 20  wrapper.java.library.path.1=C:/opt/CruiseControl/2.8.4/lib/wrapper
 56  wrapper.logfile=C:/Work/CruiseControl/logs/wrapper.log
```